# How [if it is possible] do I buy a space in a remote UNIX server?

Tags: networking

I want to get some space in a remote server running Linux. The idea is to create my custom scripts and run them on the remote server.
Idea is this: I am sitting in my class on my windows machine; I fire up terminal and connect to some remote host and am suddenly in a Linux environment.
So is it possible to buy a private space in a remote Linux/UNIX server?

[I have no idea about networking, so I really don't know if this question is stupid or super simple]

Gill Bates

Comment: It's not a programming-related question, that's for sure.  Possibly this is more suited to the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) site.  Myself, I use BlueHost as a web space provider.  They also have SSH access.  Might be overpowered for your purposes, but it's cheap enough.  For personal Linux stuff I have an old Pentium 4 machine at home running Slackware, which I can access remotely via dynamic DNS.  It's quite handy that it also does firewalling, manages my home network and keeps all my data on a large RAID array.

Comment: Thanks. I found what I was looking for: an unmanaged VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use SSH (In windows go with PuTTY).  You can use a web based server (like a web host) many give shell access, Hostgator I know does.  Or get a micro instance on Amazon Web Services.  Or better yet for a student just set up a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a slightly different approach and download Oracle's VirtualBox Software and run a virtual Linux environment in it. This would allow you to keep your current OS, have a Linux environment and save your money.

[Oracle VirtualBox Download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)